# Material-UI: Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using the Dialog and Select components from Material-UI and React.

Just an example:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Dialog, MenuItem, Select } from '@material-ui/core';

class SomeComponent extends React.PureComponent {

  render() {
    return (
      <Dialog>
        <Select
          value={this.state.age}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        >
          <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
        </Select>
      </Dialog>
    );
  }

}
```

After clicking on the select, i'm getting this error from Modal.js:

> "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded. at
>   HTMLDocument.Modal._this.enforceFocus (Modal.js?86a5:197)"

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: As far as I am aware of, you cannot use state in PureComponents.

Comment: @PiyushZalani yes you can. and the code is only an example.

Comment: You've got two infinite loops between two "modals" both demanding focus. The Dialog and the Select popover components are fighting for focus. The suggestion  `disableEnforceFocus` prop is best bet for now.

Comment: Please check on this https://stackoverflow.com/q/74010798/14607007 and help me as well.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Add the prop **disableEnforceFocus** to the Dialog component.

Reference: [issues/10341](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/10341)

**UPDATE 03/2023:**

from the [docs](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/modal/):

> Generally this should never be set to true as it makes the modal less
> accessible to assistive technologies, like screen readers.

Maybe need to add `disablePortal` as suggested [here](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/10341#issuecomment-770784016)

```
import React from 'react';
import { Dialog, MenuItem, Select } from '@material-ui/core';

class SomeComponent extends React.PureComponent {

  render() {
    return (
      <Dialog
        disableEnforceFocus
      >
        <Select
          value={this.state.age}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        >
          <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
        </Select>
      </Dialog>
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: disablePortal worked for me.

Comment: `enforceFocus={false}` should work

Comment: It's recommended not to make disbaleEnforceFocus true due to accessibility reasons. https://mui.com/material-ui/api/modal/

Answer (score 1):

At mui v4 you can use `disableEnforceFocus` check [docs](https://v4.mui.com/api/modal/#props)