# RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded. TrapFocus Error

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Error I am getting is
*Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.* which is a TrapFocus error.
I tried using props such as **disableEnforceFocus, disablePortal, enforceFocus={false}**
However, not sure where is the mistake.

The dependencies I am using are :
"@material-ui/core": "^4.11.0",
"@material-ui/pickers": "^3.2.10",

Can someone help me out?

```
import * as React from 'react';
import MenuItem from '@mui/material/MenuItem';
import FormControl from '@mui/material/FormControl';
import Select from '@mui/material/Select';

export default function MultipleSelect(props) {
  const { options, filters, setFilters, id}= props  
  const [sourceId, setSourceId] = React.useState([]);

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault(true);
    const {
        target: { value },
    } = event;

    setFilters({...filters, [id]: value});

    setSourceId(
      typeof value === 'string' ? value.split(',') : value,
    );
  };

  return (
      <FormControl sx={{ width: 250 }}>
        <Select
          multiple
          id={id}
          options={options}
          value={sourceId}
          onChange={handleChange}
          enforcefocus={false}
        >
          {options.map((option) => (
            <MenuItem
              key={option.id}
              value={option.id}
            >
              {option.name}
            </MenuItem>
          ))}
        </Select>
    </FormControl>
  );
}
```

Here is the error:

```
TrapFocus.js:214 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.
    at HTMLDocument.contain (TrapFocus.js:214:1)
    at HTMLDocument.contain (Unstable_TrapFocus.js:84:1)
    at HTMLDocument.contain (TrapFocus.js:214:1)
    at HTMLDocument.contain (Unstable_TrapFocus.js:84:1)
    at HTMLDocument.contain (TrapFocus.js:214:1)
    at HTMLDocument.contain (Unstable_TrapFocus.js:84:1)
    at HTMLDocument.contain (TrapFocus.js:214:1)
    at HTMLDocument.contain (Unstable_TrapFocus.js:84:1)
    at HTMLDocument.contain (TrapFocus.js:214:1)
    at HTMLDocument.contain (Unstable_TrapFocus.js:84:1)
    at HTMLDocument.contain (TrapFocus.js:214:1)
    at HTMLDocument.contain (Unstable_TrapFocus.js:84:1)
    at HTMLDocument.contain (TrapFocus.js:214:1)
    at HTMLDocument.contain (Unstable_TrapFocus.js:84:1)
    at HTMLDocument.contain (TrapFocus.js:214:1)
    at HTMLDocument.contain (Unstable_TrapFocus.js:84:1)
    at HTMLDocument.contain (TrapFocus.js:214:1)
    at HTMLDocument.contain (Unstable_TrapFocus.js:84:1)
    at HTMLDocument.contain (TrapFocus.js:214:1)
    at HTMLDocument.contain (Unstable_TrapFocus.js:84:1)
    at HTMLDocument.contain (TrapFocus.js:214:1)
    at HTMLDocument.contain (Unstable_TrapFocus.js:84:1)
    at HTMLDocument.contain (TrapFocus.js:214:1)
    at HTMLDocument.contain (Unstable_TrapFocus.js:84:1)
    at HTMLDocument.contain (TrapFocus.js:214:1)
    at HTMLDocument.contain (Unstable_TrapFocus.js:84:1)
    at HTMLDocument.contain (TrapFocus.js:214:1)
    at HTMLDocument.contain (Unstable_TrapFocus.js:84:1)
    at HTMLDocument.contain (TrapFocus.js:214:1)
    at HTMLDocument.contain (Unstable_TrapFocus.js:84:1)
    at HTMLDocument.contain (TrapFocus.js:214:1)
    at HTMLDocument.contain (Unstable_TrapFocus.js:84:1)
    at HTMLDocument.contain (TrapFocus.js:214:1)
    at HTMLDocument.contain (Unstable_TrapFocus.js:84:1)
    at HTMLDocument.contain (TrapFocus.js:214:1)
    at HTMLDocument.contain (Unstable_TrapFocus.js:84:1)
    at HTMLDocument.contain (TrapFocus.js:214:1)
    at HTMLDocument.contain (Unstable_TrapFocus.js:84:1)
    at HTMLDocument.contain (TrapFocus.js:214:1)
    at HTMLDocument.contain (Unstable_TrapFocus.js:84:1)
    at HTMLDocument.contain (TrapFocus.js:214:1)
    at HTMLDocument.contain (Unstable_TrapFocus.js:84:1)
    at HTMLDocument.contain (TrapFocus.js:214:1)
    at contain (Unstable_TrapFocus.js:84:1)
    at Unstable_TrapFocus.js:116:1
```

Comment: It is a known issue for v4 of your dependency: https://github.com/mui/material-ui-pickers/issues/2033. The repo has been officially archived and you should consider upgrading to v5 instead.